# Django: Reducing database queries

Tags: django

I have the following two queries in my Django view:

```
current_events = user.ambassador_profile.first().events.all().filter(end_date__gt=now)
past_events = user.ambassador_profile.first().events.all().filter(end_date__lt=now)
```

I am not sure, but is there a better way to combine these. Currently, I am doing two queries in my database and I feel like that's wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to filter all events except `end_date=now` you can use [`exclude`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/querysets/#exclude):

```
all_events = user.ambassador_profile.first().events.exclude(end_date=now)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`annotate` and `Case`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/conditional-expressions/#case) to add an attribute to each object that says if it is "current" or not

```
user.ambassador_profile.first().events.all().annotate(
    current=Case(
        When(end_date__gt=now, then=Value(True)),
        default=Value(False),
        output_field=BooleanField()
    )
)
```